# How to search for a string in a cell and take the word next to it delimited by space

Tags: excel, vba

Hi please help me with the below stuff
I need to search for a word "check" from the text in a cell in excel and take the word exactly next to it using VBA
For example if I have the below text in cell(1,B)
this is sample data to check flow

Now macro should search for the word check and give me the word flow as my output.

Comment: why not use Index Match? Can this be in any column you are searching? And what do you mean by delimited by space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function findWord(rng As Range, criterion As String)

    Dim cellContent As String
    cellContent = rng.Value

    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = Split(cellContent, " ")

    found = False

    For Each element In myArray
        If found = True Then
            findWord = element
            Exit For
        End If

        If element = criterion Then
            found = True
        End If
    Next element



End Function
```

[image]

Comment: If that works for you I would appreciate it if you accept it :)

Comment: It is working .. thank you. But I have a query here to add on this. for suppose I have a text like this "this is sample data to check flow-1 and to check flow-2 ". Can you please let me how can I retrieve both flow-1 and flow-2 (it can be till flow-n) into same cell adjacent to it.

Comment: You should open a new question for that. A good name would be "UDF Multi-Cell Array Formula to find multiple substrings in Cell" I think I can work out an answer by tonight

Comment: Thanks for that! And in the above base scenario which I have mentioned if the text is "this is sample data to check                  flow" , I will be getting the result as spaces. (Space is treated as the next string and thus it is gives the space as output) Is there a way to ignore spaces and get the word?

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, the above code works for the sample sentence as it used `spaces` as delimiter. Do you have `double spaces` in your text?

Comment: Yeah, it can have any number of spaces after the word check.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this function

```
Function GetNextWord(cell As Range, word As String)
    Dim words As Variant
    words = Split(cell.Text, " ")

    Dim index  As Variant
    index = Application.Match(word, words, 0)

    If Not IsError(index) Then If index <= UBound(words) Then GetNextWord = words(index)
End Function
```

Comment: I have a query here. We are splitting with spaces (Split(cell.Text, " ")) . what if the word I am searching for starts I new line inside the cell. Is there a way to distinguish the new line inside cell?                                                                                                       "this is new logic to 
check flow-1
in new line" something like this in a cell